# Is this code abusing the Observer Pattern?

Tags: java, design-patterns, observer-pattern

If an Observable object notifies its Observers when one or more of the variables (animals) below is assigned to a new animal, is this an improper use of the Observer Pattern since the Observer will end up setting all four animals when only a subset of them have changed? If so, how could this be fixed? Also, how could an interface be constructed that would specify that the Observer is to set those specific animals and that the Observable is to notify the Observers if those animals are changed? Thanks in advance.

```
public class ObserverClass implements Observer {
    public void update(Observable o, Object o1) {
        setHippo(o.getHippo());
        setBassetHound(o.getBassetHound);
        setOstrich(o.getOstrich());
        setAntelope((o.getAntelope());
    }
}
```

Comment: Is setting all the animals when only a subset has changed, really a problem?

Comment: That's what I'm wondering. It isn't a performance drain, I'm not sure if it is bad design?

Comment: what is making you think that it is something that needs to be "fixed"?

Comment: In a dream not long past, the clouds parted and a beam of light shone down upon me. As I peered into the celestial expanse, James Gosling descended wearing a robe adorned with magnificent jewels. It was then, there, inexplicably, that he beseached unto me, "An Observer variable updated unnecessarily is a scorn upon the Gang of Four."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Updating only a subset

Most of the time, it is not a problem, there are few instructions that will just *refresh* the values.
However, if you want to update a subset, you should use the second argument of `update` and set it to a discriminant that will tell what to update. For this you may use a set of the types of objects that have changed.

- Observing specific animals

Often, you will just begin the code of your observer by `if (!should_observe(x)) return;` where `should_observe` tells whether the object will be observed.

The other way of doing it is to create an observable that will be an oberver.
A quick example is easier to understand:

```
public class OvervableAnimal extends Observable implement Observer {
  private Class<?> animal;
  // constructor omitted
  public synchronized void update(Observable o, Object arg) {
    if (!animal.isInstance(arg))
      return; // not the right animal
    setChanged();
    notifyObservers(arg);
  }
}
ObserverClass obs;
ObserverAnimal obsHippo = new ObservableAnimal(Hippo.class);
obs.addObserver(obsHippo);
// use obsHippo if you want to be notified when a hippo has changed
```

Sometimes it is easier to reimplement entirely the observer pattern: it gives you more control and your *observable* may be an interface so you won't need to subtype.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `notifyObservers(Object)` to send information about what state has changed (which will be passed in as the second argument to the `update()` method).  how you encode the changes are up to you.  Obviously, you could send a List of the changed animals, but you'd have to do some ugly if blocks to get the animals into the right setters.